# how to convert from ZonedDateTime to Joda DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, threetenbp

I've switched to threeten for date times but I've still got a 3rd party tool that uses joda to write timestamp with timezone to the database and I need to convert from one to the other.
What's the best way?
As a workaround I tried DateTime.parse(zdt.toString) but it falls over because joda doesn't like the zone format

Invalid format: "2015-01-25T23:35:07.684Z[Europe/London]" is malformed at "[Europe/London]"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
  ZonedDateTime.of(
    2015, 1, 25, 23, 35, 7, 684000000, 
    ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

System.out.println(zdt); // 2015-01-25T23:35:07.684Z[Europe/London]
System.out.println(zdt.getZone().getId()); // Europe/London
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()); // 1422228907684

DateTimeZone london = DateTimeZone.forID(zdt.getZone().getId());
DateTime dt = new DateTime(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), london);
System.out.println(dt); // 2015-01-25T23:35:07.684Z
```

In case the zone id transformation might crash for any unsupported or unrecognized id, I recommend to

- catch and log it,
- do updates of tz-repositories (for Joda: update to latest version, for JDK: use tz-updater-tool)

That is usually the better strategy than to just silently fall back to any arbitrary tz-offset like UTC.

Comment: To the downvoters, think twice before you are going to use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(...)` as suggested in the answer of James Ding. Switching back to UTC for unsupported ids is probably worse than a crash.

Answer (score 22):

Please notice that using DateTimeZone.forID(...) is not safe, which might throw DateTimeParseException as usually ZoneOffset.UTC has a ID "Z" which cannot be recognized by DateTimeZone.

What I would recommend in order to convert ZonedDateTime to DateTime is:

```
return new DateTime(
    zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
    DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDateTime.getZone())));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. We ran into this exact issue!

Comment: @ChrisDekker There is no perfect transformation of zone identifiers in every case. While the expression `TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId)` might better work for Z-literals (representing UTC) than Joda-Time, such an expression can silently fail for other ids, but not with an exception, instead with arbitrary fallback to UTC (which is even worse), see the API-doc: "Returns:the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood", my answer just addresses the special example the OP presented in the question, but I don't pretend it to work for every zone id.

Comment: The main problem of this suggested answer is that it pretends to work for all identifiers although unrecognized ids can just be switched to UTC by the expression `TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId)` - without any exception. The underlying timezone repositories of Joda-Time and JDK know different sets of valid ids, and this fact cannot be cured by any "genious" or "smart" transformation code.

Answer (score 2):

here's a kotlin extension to do the same (in case you code that way)

```
fun ZonedDateTime.toDateTime(): DateTime =
    DateTime(this.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 
        DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(this.zone)))
```