# No instant converter found for type: java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, zoneddatetime

I'm trying to fetch lower/upper endpoint from range and when it comes to fetch these lower/upper Endpoints it throws exception which goes like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: java.time.ZonedDateTime

    at org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager.getInstantConverter(ConverterManager.java:166)
    at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:171)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:257)
```

The code:

```
@Override
    public WeatherStatus getForecastForFlightOverall(String icao, ... flight) {

       ...

        if ( flightmapIntegration.isMetIntegrationEnabled() ) {
            List<ViewFlightAirportDTO> airports = getRoutes(icao, flight);
            Range<ZonedDateTime> range = getRange(airports);

            DateTime from = range.lowerEndpoint() == null ? null : new DateTime(range.lowerEndpoint());
            ...

            try {
               ....
            }
        }

        return status != null ? status : WeatherStatus.UNKNOWN;
    }
```

getRange method:

```
 private Range<ZonedDateTime> getRange(List<...> ...) {

        if ( ....isEmpty() ) {
            return Range.singleton(ZonedDateTime.now());
        }

        Range<ZonedDateTime> result = validityRangeOf(....get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < flightAirports.size(); i++) {
            result = ...
        }

        return result;
    }
```

validtyRangeOf method:

```
private Range<ZonedDateTime> validityRangeOf(ViewFlightAirportDTO firstAirport) {
        return Range.closed(firstAirport.getValidFrom(), firstAirport.getValidTill());
    }
```

EDIT
I can make like this, but do not know how to finish it. I mean from/to can be also type of ZonedDateTime but I do not know how to create object of it with lower/upper Endpoint

```
   ZonedDateTime from = range.lowerEndpoint() == null ? null : new ZonedDateTime(...);
            ZonedDateTime to = ...
```

Comment: You can't pass a ZonedDateTime as argument to the DateTime constructor. That's what this message means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert from ZonedDateTime to Joda DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142915/how-to-convert-from-zoneddatetime-to-joda-datetime)

Comment: The Range is a Range<ZonedDateTime>. Why would you want to create a new ZonedDateTime from a value that is already a ZonedDateTime? Just use `range.lowerEndpoint()` directly.

Comment: @JBNizet damn. I was blind. Thanks/.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to convert from `ZonedDateTime` to `DateTime` by calling the constructor directly.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(zonedDateTime); // will cause IllegalArgumentException
```

You need to call a different constructor to make this conversion:

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(zonedDateTime.getZone().getId()); // extract DateTimeZone separately
new DateTime(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), dateTimeZone); // convert using epoch milliseconds
```

This will allow you to do this conversion.

Comment: `range.lowerEndpoint()` and `range.upperEndpoint()` are already `ZonedDateTime` objects. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in your edit.